# Using CSLA.NET with Active Directory

Tags: .net

Has anyone implemented Active Directory verification instead of SQL Server with this framework? Where can I find some information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would more than likely need to implement the something like [this](http://www.willasrari.com/blog/query-active-directory-users-using-c/000133.aspx) in a DataPortal_Fetch of a EditableRootList. You would pass the AD Object as an argument to the Child's constructor and populate the BO.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))